# Cannot convert value of type '[NSLayoutConstraint]' error in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add constraint to the `UIImageView` by adding this line of code:

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": userProfileImageView]))
```

But xcode show me this error:

[image]

How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `addConstraints`, instead of `addConstraint`.
`constraintsWithVisualFormat` returns an array.

Your code becomes:

```
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[v0]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v0": userProfileImageView])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let horizontalprofileViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": userProfileImageView]
```

If you click option and hover over `horizontalprofileViewConstraint` you will see its type as `[NSLayoutConstraint]` which is already an array.

So what you can do is:

```
view.addConstraints(horizontalprofileViewConstraint)
```

if you have more than one view then you cand do:

```
view.addConstraints(horizontalprofileViewConstraint + verticalprofileViewConstraint)
```

The `+` joins to arrays for you.